# Fijar una Columna en Html

Tags: html5, css3

Buenas tardes!

Quisiera saber si alguien podría ayudarme con lo siguiente, tengo una tabla donde necesito que la primer columna de ella quede siempre fija, o sea que se habilite el scroll en la parte inferior y de ahí se pueda mover el cuerpo pero no la primer columna , alguna idea ?

Comment: ¿Qué haz intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: puedes crear dos tablas, una de una sola columna al lado izquierdo de la otra

Comment: Intente lo de los divs pero no me funciona ya que es una tabla que se crea consumiendo un servicio , por ende si lo divido los estilos de stylus se dañan.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo algunos ejemplos que encontré apropiados para lo que necesitas:

[Tabla de Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/4XG7T/3/) con primera columna fija

[Otra tabla](http://jsbin.com/nolanole/1/edit?html,js,output) algo más compleja pero también con su primera columna fija

[Una forma bastante simple de hacerlo](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/)  con JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez podrías utilizar el ejemplo de la página de stylus y adaptarlo a tu página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stylus-lang.com/s/style.css" />
    <script src="//stylus-lang.com/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//stylus-lang.com/js/vendor/respond.js-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stylus-lang.com/s/codemirror.css"/>
        <script src="//stylus-lang.com/try/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="//stylus-lang.com/try/stylus.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//stylus-lang.com/try/codemirror.js"></script>
        <script src="//stylus-lang.com/try/css-mode.js"></script>
        <script src="//stylus-lang.com/try/try.js"></script>
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <aside class="sidebar">
        </aside>
        <main class="content">
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```